# ¿Pueden decirme dónde está el error?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, insert

soy muy nueva en lo que es Base de Datos y PHP. 
Creé un formulario en el que debo ingresar los datos de un expositor en una tabla PRINCIPAL con el mismo nombre, a la vez debo agregar su Profesión, Empresa, País, donde también debo registrarlas en otras tablas. En fin, son tablas relacionadas. 
Lo que intenté hacer primero fue revisar si el expositor ya existe en la tabla, si no existe entonces pasaría a registrarlo empezando por revisar si el país ingresado es nuevo o también existe, si es nuevo lo insertaría, y así con las otras dos tablas más... pero al final al ejecutar el formulario de mi página me sale que no se pudo insertar al expositor... **No me dice dónde exactamente está el error.**
Saludos, espero puedan ayudarme... 
Estoy nerviosa porque es una tarea para la universidad y además de insertar los datos luego debo modificarlos/eliminarlos :(. 
No sé si logré explicarme bien... Así que paso a mostrar mi código:

```
<?php
include "Conexion.php";

//Recibir y almacenar datos
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$apePat = $_POST["primerApellido"];
$apeMat = $_POST["segundoApellido"];
$edad = $_POST["edad"];
$profesion = $_POST["profesion"];
$empresa = $_POST["empresa"];
$correo = $_POST["correo"];
$telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
$pais = $_POST["pais"];
$hojaVida = $_POST["hojaVida"];
$foto = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']));

$expositor = "SELECT *  FROM expositor WHERE nombre = '$nombre' AND apePat = '$apePat' AND apeMat = '$apeMat'";
$validarExpositor = mysqli_query($conexion, $expositor);
$expositorRepetido = mysqli_num_rows($validarExpositor);

if(empty($nombre) || $expositorRepetido > 0){
    echo 'El expositor no es válido. Inténtelo de nuevo con otro';
}else {
    $extraerProfesion = "SELECT * FROM profesion WHERE nombreProfesion = '$profesion'";
    $validarProfesion = mysqli_query($conexion, $extraerProfesion);
    $profesionRepetida = mysqli_num_rows($validarProfesion);
    if($profesionRepetida = 0) {
        $insertarProfesion = "INSERT INTO profesion(nombreCarreraExpo) VALUES ('$profesion')";
        $resultado1 = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertarProfesion);
    }
    $extraerEmpresa = "SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE nombreEmpresa = '$empresa'";
    $validarEmpresa = mysqli_query($conexion, $extraerEmpresa);
    $empresaRepetida = mysqli_num_rows($validarEmpresa);
    if($empresaRepetida = 0) {
        $insertarEmpresa = "INSERT INTO empresa(nombreEmpresa) VALUES ('$empresa')";
        $resultado2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertarEmpresa);
    }
    $extraerPais = "SELECT * FROM pais WHERE nombrePais = '$pais'";
    $validarPais = mysqli_query($conexion, $extraerPais);
    $paisRepetido = mysqli_num_rows($validarPais);
    if($paisRepetido = 0) {
        $insertarPais = "INSERT INTO pais(nombrePais) VALUES ('$pais')";
        $resultado3 = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertarPais);
    }
    $insertarExpositor = "INSERT INTO expositor (nombre, apePat, apeMat, edad, idProfesion, idEmpresa, correo, telefono, idPais, hojaVida, foto) VALUES ('$nombre', '$apePat', '$apeMat', '$edad', (SELECT idProfesion FROM profesion WHERE nombreProfesion = '$profesion'), (SELECT idEmpresa FROM empresa WHERE nombreEmpresa = '$empresa'), '$correo', '$telefono', (SELECT idPais FROM pais WHERE nombrePais = '$pais'), '$hojaVida', '$foto')";
    $resultadoExpositor = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertarExpositor);
    if($resultadoExpositor){
        echo '<script>
                alert("¡Expositor registrado exitosamente!");
                window.history.go(-1);
            </script>';
    }else {
        echo "<script>
                alert('Error al registrar al expositor. Inténtelo de nuevo.');
                window.history.go(-1);
                </script>";
    exit;
    }
}
 mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Comment: ¿El mensaje que te sale es el del alert en javascript (Error al registrar al expositor. Inténtelo de nuevo)?

Comment: Exacto, me sale ese mensaje...

Comment: En ese caso, lo que suelo hacer, es depurar el proceso paso a paso, si directamente se rompe PHP, simplemente comento todo y voy descomentando por partes hasta dar con el problema. Si el proceso de PHP sigue adelante hasta el final, una buena opción es ir mostrando las SQL que se van generando, en tu caso, como las tienes en variables, es muy sencillo; debajo del alert, pon console.log({$insertarExpositor}) y así con todas las SQL, será sencillo dar con el problema.

Comment: Si aún así no das con el problema, ahora que tienes las SQL generadas en la consola, cópialas directamente en la base de datos (por ejemplo, phpmyadmin) a ver si te devuelve un error. Por cierto, no es buena idea meter los datos de un form directamente en una SQL sin tratar, el código se vuelve vulnerable a ataques de SQL Injection.

Comment: Otra sugerencia que te puedo dar, es que uses transacciones, de esta forma, si el proceso falla, no tendrás registros perdidos, por ejemplo, un expositor del país andorra que no tienes en la base de datos, pero en posteriores inserts, falla el registro, entonces no se completa, pero tendrás un país no vinculado a ningún otro registro, en este caso tal vez sea hasta deseable, así ya lo tienes, pero puede darse el caso que no sea deseado, si usas transacciones, puedes hacer rollback y todos los inserts se deshacen.